# Extjs build failed to resolve dependency Ext.app.Application

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to build a newly created Ext js application and I get an error :

```
$ sencha app watch

[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.app.Application for file StatsApp.Application
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.app.Application
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.p
[ERR] erformTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 1 second

[ERR] /home/cyprien/bin/Sencha/Architect/Cmd/6.6.0.13/plugin.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cyprien/projets/statsAppNew/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:252: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cyprien/projets/statsAppNew/.sencha/app/watch-impl.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cyprien/projets/statsAppNew/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:386: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cyprien/projets/statsAppNew/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:436: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.app.Application
```

I tried to add the require to the file like this :

```
// Application.js
Ext.define('StatsApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

   requires: [
      'Ext.app.Application'
    ],
```

Sencha Cmd v6.6.0.13

I have made a repository here :
[statsApp-debug on github](https://github.com/Ctaque/statsApp-debug)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to specify a `toolkit` config for your custom `web` build profile in `app.json`.